Setting visibility of ImageView in button callback not working
I'm new to app-coding, Kotlin, XML, etc. (Started teaching myself last week). I'm trying to write an activity in which an image is shown, and the user needs to press the corresponding button. (Specifically the image is of a g-clef note, and the buttons are just a list of note names, in Hebrew).
After pressing the button, I collect "correct or not" statistics, and show a "v" or "x" image so the user knows if they got it right, and then a new image is generated, until I've cycled through all images in the list of images to be learned.
The way I've got it set up, is that when a new image is generated, I redefine the button callbacks so that the correct button shows the "v" (and does a +1 to the correct answer stats, and moves on to the next image), and all the rest of the buttons show the "x" (and do a +1 to the incorrect stats, and don't move on to the next image yet).
The problem I'm facing is that everything works except for showing the v/x image. Stats are correctly collected, I checked. Adding a short "sleep" doesn't help. What am I doing wrong?
Here's the code for what it's worth. I've marked by comment the two lines that don't do what I think they should, with the words "THIS IS NOT SHOWING".
BTW, I'm sure there are a ton of improvements to be made in this code, but as a beginner I'd appreciate focusing on the problem at hand and not on the plethora of general problems in my code, style, etc.
package com.example.test

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat

class GuessNotesGame : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_guess_notes_game)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        val buttonschoicecontainer = findViewById<HorizontalScrollView>(R.id.scrollviewer)
        val linearbuttons = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.linearbuttons)

        val correctim = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.correctim)
        val wrongim = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.wrongim)
        correctim.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        wrongim.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

        buttonschoicecontainer.visibility = View.INVISIBLE;
        linearbuttons.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
        val listofnotes = listOf("c1", "d1", "e1", "f1", "g1", "a1", "b1", "c2")

        for (note in listofnotes) {
            val id: Int = resources.getIdentifier("choose" + note, "id", this.packageName)
            val btn_by_id = findViewById<Button>(id);
            btn_by_id.visibility = View.INVISIBLE;}

        val notesPlaceHolder = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.notesplaceholder)

        val notesList = listOf(
            R.drawable.c1,
            R.drawable.d1,
            R.drawable.e1,
            R.drawable.f1,
            R.drawable.g1,
            R.drawable.a1,
            R.drawable.b1,
            R.drawable.c2)
        val notesNamesList = listOf("דו", "רה", "מי", "פה", "סול", "לה", "סי", "דו גבוה")

//            notesnameslist.shuffled()

        var numCorrect = 0
        var curIndex = 0
        var numIncorrect = 0

        fun runNextNote(ind: Int) {
            correctim.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            wrongim.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

            val curCorrectNote = notesList[ind]
            val correctNoteName = notesNamesList[ind]
            notesPlaceHolder.setImageResource(curCorrectNote);
            buttonschoicecontainer.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
            linearbuttons.visibility = View.VISIBLE;

            for (note in listofnotes) {
                val id: Int = resources.getIdentifier("choose" + note, "id", this.packageName)
                val btn_by_id = findViewById<Button>(id);
                btn_by_id.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
                btn_by_id.setOnClickListener({
                    if (btn_by_id.text.toString() == correctNoteName) {
                        correctim.visibility = View.VISIBLE; // THIS
                        Thread.sleep(1_000)
                        curIndex = curIndex + 1
                        numCorrect = numCorrect + 1
                    }
                    else {
                        wrongim.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
                        Thread.sleep(1_000)
                        numIncorrect = numIncorrect + 1;
                    }
//                        Thread.sleep(2_000)
                    if (ind < notesNamesList.size - 1) {runNextNote(curIndex)}
                    else {
                        correctim.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                        wrongim.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                        val textViewResults = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewResults);
                        textViewResults.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
                        notesPlaceHolder.setImageResource(R.drawable.gcleftreb)
                        textViewResults.text = "Correct: $numCorrect, Wrong: $numIncorrect";
                    }

                }
                );}



        }

        runNextNote(0)

    }

}


As per request, here's the XML of said activity:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".GuessNotesGame">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notesplaceholder"
        android:layout_width="253dp"
        android:layout_height="306dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="128dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="128dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="165dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/introim" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollviewer"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="101dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="128dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="128dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="invisible">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearbuttons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:visibility="invisible">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/choosec1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/c1"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                tools:visibility="invisible"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/choosed1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/d1"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                tools:visibility="invisible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/choosee1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/e1"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                tools:visibility="invisible"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/choosef1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/f1"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                tools:visibility="invisible"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/chooseg1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/g1"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                tools:visibility="invisible"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/choosea1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/a1"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                tools:visibility="invisible"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/chooseb1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/b1"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                tools:visibility="invisible"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/choosec2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/c2"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                tools:visibility="invisible"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wrongim"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="128dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="128dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="69dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/notesplaceholder"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewResults"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/wrong"
        tools:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/correctim"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="128dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="128dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="69dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/notesplaceholder"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewResults"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/correct"
        tools:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewResults"
        android:layout_width="203dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="106dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="102dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="invisible" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


please, attach the file xml to make your code more readable. :)

@sadewawicak Done :-)

You are doing things in a very non-standard way. Most of this code does not belong in setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener - that listener should be used for only the stuff that needs to happen when the screen is rendered and can't be done elsewhere (like special cases where you need to adjust margins).  If you are going to call         enableEdgeToEdge() it should be called before super.onCreate().  You should also enable viewbinding it will make your life easier.  I know you asked for help with just the code that isn't working, but the way the code is written makes it hard for people to analyze.

@jt-gilkeson accepted. Where should the rest of the code go? (The parts that are the actual functionality and not the screen rendering stuff). I'll rewrite my code as necessary, and maybe the bug will become more apparent even to me.

@jt-gilkeson - I moved the functionality into onStart. The problem persists...

I've finally figured it out!
Basically, the whole problem was due to timing issues.
The Sleep method wasn't helping because the pause was for a separate thread, and the invisibility was being invoked before the visibility could kick in.
Using a Timer().scheduled didn't work because the whole thing would crash (because invoking the runNextNote function includes handling ui components), and I finaly learned about using a Handler, which allowed for adding the delay to muliple lines of code which included UI elements!
So now it's working, or more precisely - I've finaly moved on to other bugs in my code...

The requirement for a delay suggests a race-condition, which implies that Handler isn't the proper solution. This appears to be a lifecycle issue, where onStart() should rather be onCreate(). Refer to the documentation, which explains this in detail: The activity lifecycle.

This here actually hides the view in the preview only, which might only be confusing;
this isn't WYSIWYG, when you hide all views in preview; for some it may make sense.
tools:visibility="invisible"

While this commonly should be displayed in preview, but not on screen:
android:visibility="invisible"
tools:visibility="visible"

And while it's based upon simple conditions, this can be done with data-binding;
This has the huge advance, that one only has to update the condition true/false.
android:visibility="@{ condition ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE }"
tools:visibility="visible"

The tools name-space is the override for the android name-space in XML preview.
